# Scalable database query

Tags: database, scalability

I have a youtube style site but it revolves around pictures.

On the homepage I want to show latest pictures that have been uploaded above the most popular pictures of all time.

Is it a good idea to do a database/cache query for every user when they hit the page in order to check what the latest images are and display them or should I do this another way to ensure the database isn't constantly flooded with requests for the latest posted pictures?

Maybe some sort of batch job?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic proactive thing you can do here is to cache the results of the DB query - either in your app code (less preferable) or in an existing piece of infrastructure integrate-able in your web "stack", for example something like Memcached:

http://memcached.org/

This has helped many a DB-backed site achieve some minimal level of scalability/performance.

Depending on your DB, you can also cache such queries as part of DB functionality itself, but it's better if you can intercept such things before they even get to the DB.

Comment: If my server only has 2gb of ram isn't it likely that the cache won't be able to hold anywhere near the amount of data required? (site is massive, lot's of photos being viewed). ?